# Grouping formatted data together with regex statement

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a regex statement to lump together data based on data indicator tags. However I feel like my current code could be simplified.

What I am trying to do is process the data after `{4:` and before `-}`. Each data point is tagged with a column reference which looks something like `:16R:`, `93B::`, `:35B:`, etc. and the data that belongs to that tag is mostly on the same line like in the this case `:16R:SUBSAFE`, but for records like `:35B:` it's data is driven to the next three lines, but the record would look like this `:35B:ISIN HK0000000000 NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF NEW LIFE-HK BOND-R /ST/123`.

What I would like to do is just grab the tags and data on put them in their own match so each record would look like

```
:16R:SUBSAFE
:16R:FIN
:35B:ISIN HK0000000000 NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF NEW LIFE-HK BOND-R /ST/123
etc.
```

event_data:

```
{1:F01QWERTY22AXXX1234567890}{2:I103QWERTY33XXXXA7}{3:{108:MT103}}{4:
:16R:SUBSAFE
:16R:FIN
:35B:ISIN HK0000000000
NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF
NEW LIFE-HK BOND-R
/ST/123
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:16R:SUBBAL
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:94C::SAFE//HK
:90B::MRKT//ACTU/HKD12,345
:98A::PRIC//20200804
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:SUBBAL
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:FIN
:16R:FIN
-}
{1:ABC123}{2:DEF567}{3:{108:MT103}}{4:
:16R:SUBSAFE
:16R:FIN
:35B:ISIN HK1111111111
NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF
NEW LIFE-HK BOND-L
/ST/123
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:16R:SUBBAL
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:94C::SAFE//HK
:90B::MRKT//ACTU/HKD12,345
:98A::PRIC//20200804
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:SUBBAL
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:FINL
:16R:FIN
-}
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
event_data = event_key.get()['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
swift_messages = re.findall(r"({.*[^}]*-})", event_data)
for message in swift_messages:
    text_block = re.search(r"{4:[^}]*-}", message)
    text_block_data = text_block.group()[3:-2].strip()
    data = text_block_data.splitlines()
    print(data)
```

And this yields what is below for each iteration of the loop.

```
[':16R:SUBSAFE',':16R:FIN',':35B:ISIN HK0000000000','NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF','NEW LIFE-HK BOND-R','/ST/123',':93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234',':93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234',':16R:SUBBAL',':93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234',':93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234',':94C::SAFE//HK',':90B::MRKT//ACTU/HKD12,345',':98A::PRIC//20200804',':19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0',':16S:SUBBAL',':19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0',':16S:FIN',':16R:FIN']
```

But as you can see the `:35B:` records are still separated by new lines so I was thinking about going back and merging that data with additional logic. But at this point I thought I may be making it a bit too complicated and was wondering if I could simplify it with a better written regex statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `event_data` contains the data as given in the question, this works:

```
for message in re.findall(r"(?<=\{4:).*?(?=-\})", event_data, re.DOTALL):
    print('Result:')
    for data in re.findall("^:(?:.(?!^:))+", message, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
        print(re.sub('\n', ' ', data))
```

The optimisations here:

- Instead of starting with the whole message, it only takes the 'body' of the `{4:.*}` element; it achieves this by matching all the text `.*` preceded by `{4:` (lookbehind) and followed by `-}` (lookahead), which are not included in the result.
- For each message, it takes as data a colon at the start of a line `^:` followed by any character `.` that is not followed by a colon at the start of a line `(?!^:)` (negative lookahead), as many times as possible.
- Instead of using `^:(.(?!^:))+`, it uses `^:(?:.(?!^:))+`, so `.findall()` will return the entire string match, instead of only returning the first subgroup matches. `?:` tells the regex engine it's a non-capturing group, which still has to be matched for a match on the whole.
- It assumes you want the linefeeds in the `:35B:` data to be replaced with spaces, perhaps that's not even needed?

The output:

```
Result:
:16R:SUBSAFE
:16R:FIN
:35B:ISIN HK0000000000 NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF NEW LIFE-HK BOND-R /ST/123
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:16R:SUBBAL
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:94C::SAFE//HK
:90B::MRKT//ACTU/HKD12,345
:98A::PRIC//20200804
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:SUBBAL
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:FIN
:16R:FIN 
Result:
:16R:SUBSAFE
:16R:FIN
:35B:ISIN HK1111111111 NEW LIFE COOL FUND - NLCF NEW LIFE-HK BOND-L /ST/123
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:16R:SUBBAL
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/12345678,1234
:93B::AVAI//UNIT/12345678,1234
:94C::SAFE//HK
:90B::MRKT//ACTU/HKD12,345
:98A::PRIC//20200804
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:SUBBAL
:19A::HOLD//HKD123456789,0
:16S:FINL
:16R:FIN
```

Comment: Mind you, this is shorter and may or may not perform better than your own code - I'd recommend testing with `timeit` in Python to see what does better. However, even if it performs better or you like short code, remember that your original code was easier to read - in the end, you have to ask how often your code is executed and how much the performance gain matters. Hard to read code is one of the main contributing factors to software being buggy or very expensive to maintain (due to the time required to decipher this dense code).